# Parsing a string to an SqlParameter's SqlDbType

Tags: .net, sql-server, parsing, sqlcommand, sqldbtype

I'm working on an application that accepts user input and in some cases feeds that input directly into a SQL Server Stored Procedure (via parameterised SqlCommand) and in other cases runs that input through a series of transformations prior to executing the SP.

I'm using `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` to get the list of parameters from the DB and then assigning those parameters' values as strings.

So far I haven't found a way to validate that the string can be parsed into the appropriate SqlDbType before executing the SP. I was hoping for something like

```
parameter.SqlDbType.TryParse(inputValue);
```

but such a method doesn't seem to exist as SqlDBType is just an enum. So far my only option is executing the SP and catching any errors that are thrown, but this doesn't seem to tell me which parameter is causing the problem, so my user is not amused.

I know I could use a switch statement on the SqlDbType and validate the input myself but this seems like a bad idea.

I have tried searching SO for this issue but the related questions all seem to revolve around parsing a string to an SqlDbType enum member, not to the actual type. The closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447906/how-to-know-check-whether-a-value-is-sqldbtype-compatible-or-not) but the only answer talks about checking it a System.Type is compatible with any SqlDbType values.

Comment: Why do you think validating user input is a bad idea?

Comment: @Blam I mean if I have to write the validation regexes myself

Comment: Regex?  Shat SQL datatype requires regex to validate?  Why is validating user a bad idea?

Comment: @Blam if you think I have misunderstood the problem and have a suggestion please go ahead and suggest it. It seems like Date, DateTime2, and DateTimeOffset don't have corresponding .NET types and therefore need string validation

Comment: What have you tried?  Show a sample of data you could not validate.  Really one of the fields on the user input is DateTimeOffset?

Comment: @Blam the parameters required for the SPs are determined at runtime, and can change over time, so yes at some point a user could be required to provide an unusual data type. However I don't really feel I need to elaborate on this as the question remains valid - I only want to know if there is an in-built method for checking if a string value is going to cause an error in an SP

Comment: Seems like you need string validation?  .NET has DateTime and DateTimeOffset.  Show one example where you need string validation and what you have tried.

Comment: @Blam I think we're deviating from the point of my question - I'm trying to avoid doing string validation by using something available within the framework. I currently have a string validation approach for any SQL data types that don't have a corresponding .NET type with a .TryParse method and it seems to be working OK, but I was hoping for a more 'native' approach built into the framework

Comment: No I have not deviated.  From my second question I asked what data types require regex to validate and you still have not answered.  You also stated that DateTimeOffet does not have a .NET type and that is incorrect.  What SQL datatypes to you feel require string validation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx